# What is wrong with this embed code?

Tags: flash, embed, space, extra

This is the embed code for .swfs I got from Adobe's site:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="620" height="480" id="indexslideshow">
<param name="movie" value="images/indexslideshow.swf"/>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="images/indexslideshow.swf" width="620" height="480">
    <param name="movie" value="images/indexslideshow.swf"/>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
<!--<![endif]-->
<a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/></a>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

It is adding extra space to the bottom of my swf in Mozilla Firefox, but works perfectly in IE. Does anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: I noticed this only happens if an extra `<embed>` is used inside the `<object>` though that's good form.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding a closing tag will help?

Add another `</object>` to the end of your block of code.

Also, try validating your HTML with the [W3 HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: There are 2 </object> tags. One's between <!--[if !IE]>--> and <!--<![endif]-->

Comment: Sorry, the other one didn't show up in the code window-thing because I neglected to add 4 spaces before it.

Answer (score -1):

Is it a margin issue?
Try wrapping your code in this:

```
<div style="margin:0; padding:0;">
...
</div>
```

and see if that tightens up the margin.  If not, you could try adding a height to the div tag that matches your swf height:

```
<div style="margin:0; padding:0; height:480px;">
...
</div>
```